# Gatsby - Creating static files with remote content

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have been struggling implementing a solution to download remote files corresponding to Gatsby pages and posts each time there is a build. I understand that there is a Wordpress source plugin which facilitates this task with images, however, these are some remote files which follow similar logic like that of the posts and pages. Eg, when we are building a page with an ID of 100, we should download a remote file to embed in the page, like from a resource http://someaddr/files/100.txt

**Edits based on Brendan's inputs below**

**Excerpt from my gatsby-node.js file**

```
  const createTXTFile = async ({ posts, gatsbyUtilities }) =>
  Promise.all(
    posts.map(({ previous, post, next }) =>
      gatsbyUtilities.actions.createPage({
        path: `./code/post-${post.id}.txt`,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/txtmaker.js`),
        context: {
          id: post.id,
        },
      })
    )
  )
```

**Excerpt from txtmaker.js**

```
import * as React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql} from "gatsby"
import axios from "axios"


const TXTMaker = (data) => {
const getTXT = (data) =>{
const TXTURL = `https://someaddr/code-`+data
     axios.get({
     url: TXTURL
 }).then(function(response){
    return response
 }).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e)
 })
 }

return getTXT()

 }


export default TXTMaker
```

The above code is clearly not building the static file, leave aside printing the codes...

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, both that involve rolling your own source nodes in gatsby-node.js:

1. Use Gatsby's [createPages API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/using-gatsby-without-graphql/) to add your private API data to props which you can pass to page components
2. Create [your own source plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/creating-a-source-plugin/) that adds your private API's data to source nodes in Gatsby's data layer

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Brendan. My problem is that I am confused on what to pass to this method... Should it be Axios get or something? I have already tried another plugin to do this task, which is gatsby-source-plugin, however, it flunks as I am not sure what to pass to the parameters like createm createNodeID, etc

Comment: Bingo! Yes, you should fetch data as normal (e.g. using Axios) and then use your data to create pages using Gatsby's createPages API. You should think of this as saying "OK, Gatsby, here's my private API's data, please create props that I can access in my page component."

Comment: If you update your question with some data that you're trying to fetch, maybe we can roll our own simple example to get you started.

Comment: Hey Brendan, I have just appended the code in question above